# In Builder pattern, what kinds of `Product`s can share the same `Builder` and the same `Director`?

Tags: design-patterns, builder

Design Patterns, by Gamma et al, describes Builder pattern:

> **Intent**
>
> Separate the construction of a complex object from its representation so that the same construction process can create
> **different  representations**
>
> **Motivation**
>
> [image]
>
> **Structure**
>
> [image]
>
> **Implementation**
>
> Why no abstract class for products? In the common case, the products produced
> by the concrete builders  differ  so greatly in their representation  that there
> is little to gain  from  **giving  different  products  a common parent  class**. In
> the RTF example, the ASCIIText and the TextWidget objects are unlikely to
> have a common interface, nor do they need one. Because the client usually
> configures  the director with the proper  concrete builder, the client is in a
> position to know which concrete subclass of Builder is in use and can handle
> its products accordingly.

Is there some condition on what kinds of `Product`s (e.g. `ASCIItext`, `TexText`, and `TextWidget` in Motivation example)   can share the same `Builder` base class and the same `Director`, since they don't share a common parent class?

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes sense but in fact I think that defining or not a base class for the Product class depends really on the way which you want to implement your builders.

I think that default implementations of the abstract builder class *may*  be aware on a base class for the Product to build but really no obligation.

For example in the quoted example, it may just append the String returned by the method to a String that is the state of the object to build.  In this case, why defining an abstract Product class ? We don't need it.

---

Even in a more complex built object for any methods implemented in the abstract builder class, you could store each part of the object to build in the state of the abstract builder class and use these parts without the need of any base class for the Product class.

**For example here is an implementation without base class for the Product**

Client :

```
Builder builder = new ParadiseWorldBuilder();
World world = director.build(builder);
```

Director :

```
World build(){    
    builder.buildLands(...); // defined in abstract class for example
    builder.buildPeople(...);
    builder.buildAnimals(...);
    return builder.getWorld();
 }
```

Abstract builder class :

```
private List<Land> lands = ...;
List<Land> getLands(){return lands;}

void buildLands(){
    for(....){ 
        lands.add(...);
    }
}
```

Concrete builder class :

```
World getWorld(){
  return new ParadiseWorld(getLands(), ...); // use the state of the abstract class
}
```

---

Now just to show you that it is a question of choice, I will change the implementation of the example and rely on a common base class for the Product class (here `World`).

**Implementation with base class for the Product**

Client :

```
Builder builder = new ParadiseWorldBuilder();
World world = director.build(builder);
```

Director :

```
World build(){    
    builder.buildLands(...); // defined in abstract class for example
    builder.buildPeople(...);
    builder.buildAnimals(...);
    return  builder.getWorld();
 }
```

Abstract builder class :

```
protected World world = createEmptyWorld(); // abstract method
void buildLands(){
    for(....){
        world.addLands(...); 
    }
}
World getWorld(){
  return world;
}
```

Abstract Product class :

```
public World{
   void addLands(...){
        // ...
   }
}
```

Product class :

```
public ParadiseWorld extends World{
     //...
}
```

Concrete builder class :

```
World createEmptyWorld(){
   return new ParadiseWorld();
}
```

IHMO in this example the approach without base class for Product is much better. It reduces the coupling between the Builders and the Products. Besides, here the hierarchy appears superficial and the delegation between the builder and the product to create for each built part looks an overhead and prevent immutability for the Product class(that may be desirable).